# How to merge between two variables like this code in php?

Tags: javascript, php

This code in php is merged between two variables and it is used in the "loops":-

```
${'var' . $i}
```

Is there's any code like this in javascript?
and if there, can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually its concatenation of the values/variable in `PHP`, and creating another variable name, and then you are trying to get the value of that variable name your formed after concatenation.

So similarly in javascript you can do with `eval` or as every root level variable is child of `window` object you are get value from `window` object also.

```js
var Var1 = "Value from Variable 1";
var Var2 = "Value from Variable 2";

//lets say you use some loop or whatsoever  to generate the variable name.

//concatenation to generate the bariable name equivalent to  'Var'.$i
var variableName = 'Var' + 1;

//now get the value equivalent to ${VariableName} 
//using evel
var value = eval(variableName);
console.log(variableName + ' = ' + value);

variableName = 'Var' + 2;
//now get the value equivalent to ${VariableName}
//using  window object
value = window[variableName];
console.log(variableName + ' = ' + value);
```

I would suggest to use `window[variableName]` its little safer that `eval()`.  Actually `eval` tries to execute the code passed to `eval` method as parameter. so if some pass some malicious code, `eval` will execute it. and other side `window` approach just try to find the variable name associate with window object, so its safer to be used

Comment: Thanks alot, it's helped, but there's somethin',
i need to write Var1, Var2, Var3 ... etc,
is there any way to make it dynamic?

Comment: you can loop it.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration